# numpy apply along axis with error "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (1)"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here's an example of my numpy array, and I would like to apply a function `mapping` for each rows of the matrix `test`.

```
test = np.array([[0, .1, .9], [.1, .9, .8], [.8, .6, .1]])
test2 = np.array(['a','b','c'])

def mapping(x):
    return test2[np.where(x > .7)].tolist()
```

this works

```
mapping(test[0]), mapping(test[1]), mapping(test[2])
```

correct result: `(['c'], ['b', 'c'], ['a','b'])`

but this doesn't, and spits out error.

```
np.apply_along_axis(mapping, 1, test)
```

I don't understand why this is the case. Please help.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is trying to create a regular array from the results.  But you rows generate a mix of lists, with 1 or2 elements.  Why are you trying to use this function?  Isn't a simple iteration over the rows enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `apply` docs:

```
The output array. The shape of `outarr` is identical to the shape of
`arr`, except along the `axis` dimension. This axis is removed, and
replaced with new dimensions equal to the shape of the return value
of `func1d`. So if `func1d` returns a scalar `outarr` will have one
fewer dimensions than `arr`.
```

What is the shape of the return value of `mapping`? `apply...` tries to guess this by doing a calculation with the first item.  In your case `['c']`.  So it attempts to return a (3,1) array, and runs into problems when your 2nd row returns values.

The best way to apply your function to the rows of `test` is:

```
In [240]: [mapping(x) for x in test]
Out[240]: [['c'], ['b', 'c'], ['a']]

In [246]: np.apply_along_axis(mapping, 1, test[[0,2],:])
Out[246]: 
array([['c'],
       ['a']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

Even where it works, `apply_along_axis` does not improve speed - in fact it's worse

```
In [249]: timeit [mapping(x) for x in test]
20.4 µs ± 33 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [250]: timeit np.array([mapping(x) for x in test])
25.1 µs ± 192 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [251]: timeit np.apply_along_axis(mapping, 1, test[[0,2,2],:])
146 µs ± 194 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops e
```